# New email envelop does not appear in notification area in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

When an email is received, Outlook 2010 creates an envelop in notification area. But when my emails are moved by a rule to some folder other than standard inbox, I dont get a notification in system tray. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I have not been able to find a way to get the mail icon to work with sub-folders. So I have posted this work around in order to get a notification for those rules you have. Hope it helps for now.

[image: Screen Shot]

In order to display desktop notification for rules which move incoming emails to specific folders, edit the rule which you are referring to. In the "actions" step where you select which fold it is moved to, scroll to the bottom. There you will find additional options for notifications. The last one is Display A Desktop Alert. Also, if you prefer, you can use the one above it to create a custom message.

Comment: That Desktop Alert is actually something different to the `notification area` (`system tray`) icon or the 'toast' popups.

Comment: @paradroid You are correct. I didn't clearify I was offering a work around. From what I found, the envelope icon only works with unread items in the Inbox, not in subfolders.

Comment: Yes.  See my answer for a fix for that.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a long time since I encountered this problem, so I may be slightly wrong about the details but, if I remember correctly, that notification icon only works with emails arriving in the main inbox folder for the primary email address.  I did not get them for emails that were moved into other folders using rules, or for other address inboxes.

The solution I found to these Outlook deficiencies is [**Bettasoft Mail Alert**](http://www.bettasoft.net/mailalert), which provides a number of flexible options.  It costs $6.95, but there is a free trial.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using large or small icons on your taskbar?  If you are using small icons, the notification does not work.